# POJO class from JSON with a value that can either be string on integer

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON file with a value "code" that can either be a string or an integer.

```
{
    "code": 110005,
    "name": "abcd"
},
{
    "code": "090270",
    "name": "efgh"
}
```

How do I create a POJO class with this?
Expected Output is string

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: hi, String for all values.

Comment: Have you tried using GSON? And defining code and string in POJO model? Looks like String will parse both

Answer (score 0):

Just create POJO with String. Whatever the value you provide for the fields, a String or integer, it would be considered as String in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the fields that contain numbers to strings:

```
const data = [{
    "code": 110005,
    "name": "abcd"
  },
  {
    "code": "090270",
    "name": "efgh"
  }
]

console.log(createObj(data))

function createObj(data) {
  return data.map(entry => {
    return {
      code: entry.code.toString(),
      name: entry.name
    }
  })
}
```